# Optimization: Via manifolds point of view of Lagrange multipliers method

Tags: optimization, manifolds, lagrange-multiplier

My basis on differential manifolds calculus and differential geometry being very superficial, I'm trying to understand this [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#Modern_Formulation_via_Differentiable_Manifolds) on WP's article.

I'm not being able to realize why most of the statements are true. For instance:

> then checking whether all the eigenvalues of the Hessian $H_xf$ are negative

Why is this necessary for the point to be a maximum (if that's the case)?

And if it wouldn't be too broad or hard to do on this format, any development of the subject (of the section) in a way that would help me gain intuitivity about this issue would be great!

Sorry if the question is poorly asked, I couldn't find another way to do it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The Hessian of a function is a generalization of the 2nd derivative of a single-variable function $f(x)$.  If $x=a$ is a critical point of $f(x)$, a sufficient criterion for $a$ be a maximum is that the second derivative of $f$ at $a$ be negative: $f''(a) < 0$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Second_derivative_test).

For multivariable functions, "second derivative" generalizes to "Hessian," and "negative (scalar)" generalizes to "negative definite (linear transformation)".  A linear transformation $A$ is said to be negative definite if $-A$ is positive-definite.  Positive-definiteness can be characterized using eigenvalues: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations.

To get comfortable with manifolds, I would recommend the relevant sections in "Ordinary Differential Equations" by V. Arnol'd and, for a more thorough calculus context, "Mathematical Analysis" by Zorich (both books are published by UniversiText).